# NextJS Build Issue and Fetching Details Issue

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13

I'm wokring on this [website](https://clushsport.soulservices.com/) so we create a nextjs build using "npm run build" command and then we run this command "npm run start" for using as a production.

Everyting works good but we face the wired issue like. In my dabatase I deleted the products. and When I check the website the products are still there. Even refreshing the website or change the browsers won't help anything.

here the sample code

```
import ChampionsinAction from "@/components/home/ChampionsinAction";
import FeaturedProduct from "@/components/home/FeaturedProduct";
import HomeBanner from "@/components/home/HomeBanner";
import HomeBlog from "@/components/home/HomeBlog";
import HomeDeisgnTool from "@/components/home/HomeDeisgnTool";
import HomeSample from "@/components/home/HomeSample";
import HomeSteps from "@/components/home/HomeSteps";
import HomeTrust from "@/components/home/HomeTrust";
import BlogService from "@/service/BlogService";
import ProductService from "@/service/ProductService";

export default async function Home() {
  const data = await getFeaturedProducts();
  const blogData = await getBlogs();
  const sampleProducts = await getSampleProducts();
  return (
    <main>
      <HomeBanner />
      <HomeDeisgnTool />
      <FeaturedProduct products={data} />
      <HomeSteps />
      <HomeSample products={data} />
      <ChampionsinAction />
      <HomeTrust />
      <HomeBlog blogData={blogData} />
    </main>
  );
}

async function getFeaturedProducts() {
  const products = ProductService.getFeaturedProducts(null);
  return products;
}

async function getBlogs() {
  const blogs = BlogService.getFrontBlogs(null);
  return blogs;
}

async function getSampleProducts() {
  const products = ProductService.getHomeSampleProducts(null);
  return products;
}
```

so here in FeaturedProduct component I'm recieving the data

Comment: Where deleted products still appear on your Next.js even after refreshing or changing browsers, can often be attributed to caching. Check the caching behavior

Comment: For dynamic, you can use ```getServerSideProps```.

Comment: @Calix I'm using app routes

Answer (score 0):

It seems the issue is due to the caching of pages and data generated by the App Router. In Next.js, you have the ability to extend the default functionality of [fetch()](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/fetching-caching-and-revalidating#segment-level-caching) to address this

```js
  // Similar to getServerSideProps
  fetch('http://sometingUrl', { cache: 'no-store' });
  // Similar to getStaticProps
  fetch('http://sometingUrl', {
    next: { revalidate: 10 },
  });
```

Additionally, you can configure settings for each [segment](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/route-segment-config) by using an export statement like `export const dynamic = "force-dynamic";`.